# Looking for a mistaken identity super hero book about a woman who works in fast food

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I read this book a few years ago. (Between 3-10) It is about a woman who keeps getting mistaken for a popular super hero and attacked by villains as she works at a fast food place. Nobody believes her when she tells them that she isn't the hero so she has to defend herself. She uses a fire extinguisher to defeat one villain. The villains do have powers but the main character does not.

There's a cop that keeps trying to get her to admit she's the super hero.

Her friend visits the fast food place and I think draws. Her friend is secretly a super hero. There's multiple mentions of insurance covering things.

I believe the superhero may turn out to be her **twin** sister in the end. It's a series that I found on goodreads. Very light and short books. Possibly novellas.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a nice description! Can you remember what the powers of the super hero were? And why she was being mistaken for them? Do the villains have powers? If you remember anything else about this please [edit] that information into your question!

Comment: How many books did you read?  Do you recall any of the cover art?

Comment: I'm going to have to check that one out. You might also enjoy Lexie Dunn's "[Superheroes Anonymous](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/SuperheroesAnonymous)" series that follows Gail Godwin, who is a perpetual hostage of supervillains due to the main hero of town frequently showing up to rescue her, and her boyfriend happens to look a lot Blaze... One departure, though, is that a few chapters into the first book, while Blaze and her boyfriend are out of town, she gets kidnapped again, isn't saved this time, and winds up with powers. And then things get complicated.

Comment: This reminds me of Penelope/Pizza Girl from the webcomic [Questionable Content](https://questionablecontent.net/) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Questionable_Content))

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### [*Night Shift*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40085461-night-shift) (2018) by Erik Schubach

*Night Shift* is the first book in the [*Emily Monroe Is Not The Chosen One* series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/232894-emily-monroe-is-not-the-chosen-one) which consists of 3 books (so far).

> Emily Monroe may be a lot of things, but one thing is for sure, she is NOT the Chosen One.
>
> Emily is a normal girl working at Big Burger who has the unfortunate luck to look exactly like Big City's superhero darling, the Chosen One.
>
> It has been the bane of her existence as it disrupts her life and those around her when super villains come knocking, wanting to prove their mettle by fighting the Chosen One. Nobody listens when she insists she isn't who they think she is.
>
> With common sense and years of rage built up inside, she usually serves their butts to them on a platter, asking "Did you want fries with that?" No cape required.

[image: Cover art for the book showing Emily sillhouetted against the moon and city scape with the superhero with their back to her]

---

Found with the Google query `fast food worker mistaken for superhero site:goodreads.com` which turned up that page as the first result.

Comment: She could make millions at welterweight MMA.